# Затемнение родительского окна (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

Те кто работал с delphi должны понять о чем речь, при открытии в модальном окне дочернего окна, нужно сделать затемнение родительского, кто знает как это сделать в wpf?

А то у нас окон много, и при открытии они немного сливаются по цветам...вообщем нужно затемнить прошлое окно, есть идеи?

Comment: Красиво конечно написано, но не работает.[![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIOkX.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIOkX.jpg)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, вам надо [вот это](http://manaspatnaik.com/blog/index.php/technology/wpf/make-parent-window-blured-for-better-focus-on-ui-in-wpf/356)

```
/// <summary>
/// Apply Blur Effect on the window
/// </summary>
/// <param name=”win”></param>
private void ApplyEffect(Window win)
{
   System.Windows.Media.Effects.BlurEffect objBlur = new System.Windows.Media.Effects.BlurEffect();
   objBlur.Radius = 4;
   win.Effect = objBlur;
}

/// <summary>
/// Remove Blur Effects
/// </summary>
/// <param name=”win”></param>
private void ClearEffect(Window win)
{
 win.Effect = null;
}
```

и, собственно, применение:

```
private void btnShowDialog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WinModalDialog objModal = new WinModalDialog();
    objModal.Owner = this;
    ApplyEffect(this);

    objModal.ShowDialog();

    ClearEffect(this);
}
```

Comment: именно это! спс

Comment: Мне понравилось! Добавил себе такую фичу... Спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Для начала полезные ссылки:

- [Shazzam Shader Editor](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=shazzam)
- [Windows Presentation Foundation Pixel Shader Effects Library](http://wpffx.codeplex.com)
- [Ссылка на готовый проект (Github)](https://github.com/Casper-SC/Wpf_ShadersExample)
- [SilverShader – Introduction to Silverlight and WPF Pixel Shaders](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/SilverShader--Introduction-to-Silverlight-and-WPF-Pixel-Shaders)

Создаёшь библиотеку типа `WPF User Control Library`, называешь её `Controls`. Удаляешь из вновь созданного проекта `UserControl`.

Создаёшь папку `Shaders`. Добавляешь класс:

**TintShaderEffect.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;

namespace Controls.Shaders
{
    public class TintShaderEffect : ShaderEffect
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty = ShaderEffect.RegisterPixelShaderSamplerProperty(
            "Input", typeof(TintShaderEffect), 0);

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TintColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "TintColor",
                typeof(Color),
                typeof(TintShaderEffect),
                new PropertyMetadata(Color.FromArgb(255, 230, 179, 77), PixelShaderConstantCallback(0)));

        public Brush Input
        {
            get { return ((Brush)(GetValue(InputProperty))); }
            set { SetValue(InputProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>The tint color.</summary>
        public Color TintColor
        {
            get { return ((Color)(this.GetValue(TintColorProperty))); }
            set { SetValue(TintColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public TintShaderEffect()
        {
            string name = AssemblyHelper.GetExecutingAssemblyName();
            Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + name + ";component/Shaders/TintShaderEffect.ps", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

            PixelShader pixelShader = new PixelShader();
            pixelShader.UriSource = uri;
            PixelShader = pixelShader;

            UpdateShaderValue(InputProperty);
            UpdateShaderValue(TintColorProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Добавляешь в проект в папку `Shaders` файл `TintShader.fx`, который содержит:

**TintShader.fx**

```
/// <summary>The tint color.</summary>
/// <type>Color</type>
/// <minValue>0,0,0,0,</minValue>
/// <maxValue>1,1,1,1</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>0.9,0.7,0.3,1</defaultValue>
float4 TintColor : register(C0);

// Sampler
sampler2D TextureSampler : register(S0);

// Shader
float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
   // Sample the original color at the coordinate
   float4 color = tex2D(TextureSampler, uv);

   // Convert the color to gray
   float gray = dot(color, float4(0.3, 0.59, 0.11, 0)); 

   // Create the gray color with the original alpha value
   float4 grayColor = float4(gray, gray, gray, color.a); 

   // Return the tinted pixel
   return grayColor * TintColor;
}
```

Устанавливаешь [Shazzam Shader Editor](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=shazzam). Выбираешь в программе `File -> New_Shader File`. Выбираешь место сохранения и называешь файл `TintShader.fx`. Далее вставляешь в редакторе код шейдера, который показан выше. Выбираешь в меню `Tools -> Compile Shader`. Далее выбираешь `Tools -> Explore Compiled Shaders`. Ищешь и открываешь папку `TintShaderEffect` (название зависит от того, как ты назвал файл шейдера). Копируешь в проект в папку `Shaders` файл `TintShaderEffect.ps`, у файла выставляешь `Действие при построении` `(Build Action)` в `Resource`.

Добавляешь класс в корень проекта `Controls`

**AssemblyHelper.cs**

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace Controls
{
    public static class AssemblyHelper
    {
        public static string GetExecutingAssemblyName()
        {
            return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Далее добавляешь в проект `Controls` класс

**CustomWindow.cs**

```
using Controls.Shaders;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;

namespace Controls
{
    public class CustomWindow : Window
    {
        public CustomWindow()
        {
            Loaded += CustomWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void CustomWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ActivateDisabledEffect();
        }

        private void CustomWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DeactivateDisabledEffect();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAutoShadingEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsAutoShadingEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomWindow), new PropertyMetadata(true,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(IsAutoShadingEnabledPropertyChanged)));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisabledEffectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DisabledEffect", typeof(Effect), typeof(CustomWindow), new PropertyMetadata(
                new TintShaderEffect() { TintColor = Colors.LightGray },
                new PropertyChangedCallback(EffectPropertiesChanged)));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty UseDisabledEffectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "UseDisabledEffect", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(EffectPropertiesChanged)));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty UseDisabledEffectInternalProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "UseDisabledEffectInternal", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(EffectPropertiesChanged)));

        private bool UseDisabledEffectInternal
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(UseDisabledEffectInternalProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UseDisabledEffectInternalProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool IsAutoShadingEnabled
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsAutoShadingEnabledProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsAutoShadingEnabledProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool UseDisabledEffect
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(UseDisabledEffectProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UseDisabledEffectProperty, value); }
        }

        public Effect DisabledEffect
        {
            get { return (Effect)GetValue(DisabledEffectProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DisabledEffectProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void IsAutoShadingEnabledPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = (CustomWindow)d;
            if (control.UseDisabledEffectInternal)
            {
                control.UseDisabledEffectInternal = false;
            }
        }

        private static void EffectPropertiesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = (CustomWindow)d;
            SetEffect(control);
        }

        private static void SetEffect(CustomWindow control)
        {
            if (!control.UseDisabledEffectInternal && !control.UseDisabledEffect)
            {
                control.Effect = null;
            }
            else if (control.UseDisabledEffect)
            {
                control.Effect = control.DisabledEffect;
            }
            else if (control.UseDisabledEffectInternal)
            {
                control.Effect = control.DisabledEffect;
            }
        }

        private void ActivateDisabledEffect()
        {
            if (Owner != null)
            {
                var window = Owner as CustomWindow;
                if (window != null)
                {
                    Closed -= CustomWindow_Closed;
                    Closed += CustomWindow_Closed;
                    if (window.IsAutoShadingEnabled)
                    {
                        window.UseDisabledEffectInternal = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }        

        private void DeactivateDisabledEffect()
        {
            var window = Owner as CustomWindow;
            if (window != null)
            {
                if (window.IsAutoShadingEnabled)
                {
                    window.UseDisabledEffectInternal = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Создаёшь основной проект, например, назвав его Wpf_Shaders.
Проект содержит в себе следующий код:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<controls:CustomWindow
    x:Class="Wpf_Shaders.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Controls;assembly=Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Ellipse
            Width="100"
            Height="100"
            Margin="60,150,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Fill="#FFBD4566"
            Stroke="Black" />
        <Ellipse
            Width="100"
            Height="100"
            Margin="353,150,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Fill="#FFA5E282"
            Stroke="Black" />
        <Ellipse
            Width="70"
            Height="70"
            Margin="0,38,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Fill="#FF289ACF"
            Stroke="Black" />
        <Button
            Padding="6,2,6,2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Click="Button_Click"
            Content="Новое окно" />
        <StackPanel
            Margin="24,10,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                Padding="6,2,6,2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Click="OnEffectButton_Click"
                Content="Включить эффект" />
            <Button
                Margin="0,3,0,0"
                Padding="6,2,6,2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Click="OffEffectButton_Click"
                Content="Выключить эффект" />
            <ToggleButton
                Margin="0,3,0,0"
                Padding="6,2,6,2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Content="Автозатенение"
                IsChecked="{Binding IsAutoShadingEnabled,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                   AncestorType={x:Type controls:CustomWindow}}}" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>

</controls:CustomWindow>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using Controls;
using System.Windows;

namespace Wpf_Shaders
{
    public partial class MainWindow : CustomWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = new SomeWindow();
            window.Owner = this;
            window.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void OnEffectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UseDisabledEffect = true;
        }

        private void OffEffectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UseDisabledEffect = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**SomeWindow.xaml**

```
<controls:CustomWindow
    x:Class="Wpf_Shaders.SomeWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Controls;assembly=Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_Shaders"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="SomeWindow"
    Width="300"
    Height="300"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</controls:CustomWindow>
```

**SomeWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using Controls;

namespace Wpf_Shaders
{
    public partial class SomeWindow : CustomWindow
    {
        public SomeWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Не забудь добавить ссылку на проект `Controls` для проекта `Wpf_Shaders`. Всё, запускаешь программу, открываешь окно нажав на кнопку "Новое окно". Появившееся окно автоматом затеняет родительское окно. Закрываешь, с родительского окна снимается шейдерный эффект. Этот эффект можно применять к любому наследнику от `UIElement`.

Следует помнить, что это пример того, как не писать много кода для применения эффекта. Можно прописать всё намного гибче в CustomWindow и, к примеру, если какое-то свойство выставлено в True, то не применять эффект и т.д. Так же не забываем, что цвет можно прописать любой. Всё это дело работает очень быстро, так как это шейдеры.

[image: Окно до нажатия на кнопку]
[image: Окно после нажатия на кнопку "Новое окно"]

Comment: Ничего себе, впечатляет.

Comment: VladD, сижу я как-то после работы, увидел этот вопрос и вспомнил, что похожую проблему я решал на предыдущей своей работе. Только я там затенял отдельные контролы. Например, на контроле два раза кликнули, открылось окно настроек, а контрол окрасился в синий оттенок, а при возникновении ошибки на одном из устройств и приходе значения от контроллера элемент окрашивался в красный. Понятное дело, что должно всё это было быстро работать.